# Videos paused outside viewport with IntersectionObserver

Tags: video, intersection-observer

I created this function that stops the videos from playing when they are outside the viewport. It doesn't work. Can you help fix it?

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => { 
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        entry.intersectionRatio > 0 ? entry.target.play : entry.target.pause()
    })
})

const videos = document.querySelectorAll('video')   
videos.forEach(video => {
    console.log('video out')
    observer.observe(video)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've found an answer already, but you're not actually invoking the `.play` method. You need to use `.play()` just like you used `.pause()`. So your third line should be:

```
entry.intersectionRatio > 0 ? entry.target.play() : entry.target.pause()
```